# Message history for outbound component

Tags: spring-integration

How should I track int-http:outbound-gateway and int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter?  Below are the mapping of the component corresponding to java classes. Please verify. 
I need to call setShouldTrack(true) method on the following bean so that I can fetch these component details in message-history (name,type,timestamp)

```
    int-ws:outbound-gateway                 org.springframework.integration.ws.MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway 
    int-http:inbound-gateway                org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway
    int-http:outbound-gateway               org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler
    int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter  org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsSendingMessageHandler 
    int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter        ??
```

Currently I am able to track int-http:inbound-gateway and int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. All the `MessageHandler` implementations in the Framework are an extension of the `AbstractMessageHandler` and there is a `setShouldTrack()` method.

If you would like to call it manually, you can get access to them via their `id`. And this one is a composed id of the wrapping consumer endpoint and `.handler` suffix: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/overview.html#endpoint-bean-names

On the other hand it isn't clear why would one do that manually, if the `<message-history>` allows us to configure patterns for component names delimited with comma: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#message-history-config